# Слетает подсветка синтаксиса в Eclipse IDE (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, настройка, color

Установил плагин Eclipse color theming. Полностью ни одна не понравилась. Поставил ту, которая подходит больше всего по цвету бэка и общей приятности.

Начал в меню Java - Editor - Syntax Color настраивать синтакс под себя. После долгой настройки обнаружил, что далеко не все настройки сохраняются. При перезагрузке редактора где-то меняется цвет, где-то шрифт становится жирным. А если в менюшке редактирования цветов я зайду куда-то не туда и изменю цвет, который не должен был - всё нахер слетит на ту тему, которую я выбрал в плагине. Что делать, чтобы всё сохранялось? Эта ide меня уже этим задолбала, вы уж извините

Answer (score 1):

Удалите этот плагин и воспользуйтесь стандартными настройками "Colors and Fonts" в Eclipse.

Comment: Удалил плагин. Темная тема осталась. Но, как я понял, та тема просто заменила цвета (которые видимо можно было настроить по умолчанию), и теперь эти цвета после удаления не откатились обратно. Попробовал что-то изменить - опять не сохраняется.

Comment: А, нет, темный фон остался стандартный. Прошелся по всему меню, нажимая Restore Defaults. Всё равно не сохраняет

Comment: Так. Без всяких плагинов, там есть несколько тем. Если в стандартной виндоусовской менять цвет синтаксиса, то он сохраняется. А если переключить на dark тему и менять - то настройки слетают